# How can i set content security policy to iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an iframe in my website i want to set content security policy inside the iframe but it's only works in my domain not inside iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'none'">
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src='https://example.com/'  width="100%" 
style="height:100vh">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found this: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: @Monkeyyy11 i want to disable css style not scripts.

Comment: Unless you can edit the source code of the iframe itself (the code generating that content), you can't.